# Can't access MariaDB from Google Cloud / Compute instance

Tags: networking, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mariadb

I can't seem to get remote access to Mysql running on a Google Cloud/Compute instance. I'm trying to do a plain vanilla install.

1. I created the instance, using Debian, the default.
2. I did the apt-get install for mysql, and bizarrely, it installed MariaDB instead. Fine.
3. I ran sudo mysql mysql_secure_installation and followed the prompts. Bizarrely, it left the mysql.users row for "root" with a plugin column value of "unix_socket", which allows only local access using sudo. Fine. I'll add a new user.
4. I logged in locally and ran:

   create user 'myname'@'%' identified by 'mypass';

   grant all privileges on * . * to 'mypass'@'%';

   flush privileges;

I can connect using 'myname' from localhost.

5. I opened up a hole in the Google Cloud firewall for port 3306 on 0.0.0.0/0. I know I did it correctly, because I created an identical rule for port 8088, and I can communicate remotely to that port just fine.
6. When I try to connect to mysql from a remote box, I get "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused."

This could be a networking problem or a mysql problem, and I can't figure out which. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Buried deep in the configuration files, at /etc/mysql/maria.conf.d/50-server.cnf, are these incredible lines:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment out the bind-address and it works.

*This* is the consequence of the exceptionally poor decision for Debian to install MariaDB when you ask for MySql. There are series of convoluted configuration files, alternately named mysql* and mariadb*, and none do what they purport to do.

Comment: In my case to allow remote access, i just commented that line (bind-address) and then, i restart mariadb, after that, i create a global user like this guide explain: https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/database-guides/how-enable-remote-access-your-mariadbmysql-database